# how params not require in url manager yii

Tags: regex, yii, yii-url-manager

I have this rule:

```
'video/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'user/pvideo/view',
```

In here the title is required. but I dont want it. so I change code to this:

```
'video/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'user/pvideo/view',
'video/<id:\d+>'=>'user/pvideo/view',
```

It's works fine.
But how can I write this in one line? I try this code:

```
'video/<id:\d+>/<title:.*>'=>'user/pvideo/view',
```

But also the title is required in here, and if don't put any chars after `video/1/` return: `HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found`

Note that I want use any `UTF-8` chars in title.
How can I have shorter code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`'video/<id:\d+>(/?<title:.*>)?'=>'user/pvideo/view'`

Comment: Do you sure about this answer? All links were of the form: `domain.com/video/14(/?aaaaa)?`

Comment: This is not just a standard regular expression, this is a pattern of Yii framework similar to regular expression.